# How do I conduct a clustering analysis if my dataset is too large?

Tags: r, bigdata, cluster-analysis

I have the following dataset as seen beneath:

```
    data.frame':    42172 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Product: Factor w/ 811 levels "P1","P2","P3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .. 
 $ Week   : Factor w/ 52 levels "W1","W2","W3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sales  : int  11 7 7 12 8 3 4 8 14 22 ...
```

Subsequently, I pre-process my data and exclude the labels "Product" and "Week" from my data set to run clustering analyses:

```
df1_labels <- df1["Product","Week"]
 df1$Product <- NULL
 df1$Week <- NULL
 str(df1)
'data.frame':   42172 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Sales: int  11 7 7 12 8 3 4 8 14 22 ...
 sc_df <- as.data.frame(scale(df1))
 summary(sc_df)
     Sales        
 Min.   :-0.7416  
 1st Qu.:-0.7416  
 Median :-0.4082  
 Mean   : 0.0000  
 3rd Qu.: 0.2584  
 Max.   : 5.3418
```

Finally, when I attempt to compute and plot a cluster I under go the following Issue:

```
dist_df <- dist(sc_df, method = 'euclidean')
hclust_avg <- hclust(dist_df, method = "average")
plot(hclust_avg)enter code here
```

Output:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.6 Gb
```

Seemingly the dataset is to big, thus what would I need to do under such circumstances?

Comment: maybe `{disk.frame}` package is what you need: https://diskframe.com/

Comment: You could use `kmeans()` clustering to combine your 42,172 observations to a smaller number of groups, e.g. 1,000 and then run `hclust()` on the groups. Also `df1 <- df$Sales` gets you the column you want without setting columns to NULL.

Comment: If you are just clustering on a single vector, "sales", what are you expecting?  You can just plot a histogram and see if there are any groupings.

Comment: you are only clustering on a single variable. a gaussian mixture will do. you don't need to calculate the distance